# How to force delete files/folders in windows using python?

Tags: python, windows

In Windows, I am aware that powershell has some provision to delete files/folders forcefully when it is in use. But in python, attempting to remove a file that is in use causes an exception like below. How to resolve this error?

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: (file-name)
```

I tried with os.remove(file_path). It works fine when file is not used by anyone.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried doing `del /f <filename>` through subprocess?

Comment: what does this have to do with powershell? why is it tagged with powershell?